# Azure devops issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job mac_agent: Step InstallAppleProvisioningProfile input provProfileSecureFile references secure file

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, provisioning-profile

i have this task in azure pipeline :

```
 - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
    inputs:
     provisioningProfileLocation: 'sourceRepository'
     provProfileSecureFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts/InHouse_com.xxxx.xxxxx.mobileprovision'
```

the file do exist in this path,
but when executing the pipeline I'm getting this error/warning :
[image]

when i manually press the button its continue,
how can I avoid this?

Comment: I'm not really into this Apple thing, but I clearly see an authorization issue. I think you must authorize somewhere before you execute this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should authorize the resource before we use it, we need click the button Authorize resources to authorize, then we can use the file in the pipeline.

Or open project settings->Settings->check the option Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines and
Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories.

Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#troubleshooting-authorization-for-a-yaml-pipeline) for more details.

[image]